# How to store data in dataframe dynamically?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one input file.

cat file

```
 ABC   2 3 4
 DEF   3 4 5 
 FRD   3 5 6

 input<-read.table(file)
```

I want to load this in dataframe where names are key and values are vector of numbers in a row so that i can get the values.

How can i store the data in dataframe dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stored those values with the first column as rownames you could access using this formalism:

```
 dfrm["ABC", ]   # result  c(2,3,4)

 dfrm <- read.table(text="V1 V2 V3
  ABC   2 3 4
  DEF   3 4 5 
  FRD   3 5 6",  header=TRUE )
dfrm["ABC" , ]
#     V1 V2 V3
# ABC  2  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `list` I guess:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:3, 
      .Label = c("ABC", "DEF", "FRD"), class = "factor"), 
      V2 = c(2L, 3L, 3L), V3 = 3:5, V4 = 4:6), 
      .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df.l <- as.list(df[,2:4])
names(df.l) <- df[,1]

# $ABC
# [1] 2 3 3

# $DEF
# [1] 3 4 5

# $FRD
# [1] 4 5 6
```

Now, you can access these vectors by doing: `df.l[["ABC"]]`

Alternatively, if you would want to keep it as a `data.frame`, you should make the first column of your `data.frame` as it's column names:

```
df.o <- df[,2:4]
names(df.o) <- df[,1]

#   ABC DEF FRD
# 1   2   3   4
# 2   3   4   5
# 3   3   5   6
```

Now, you can access it similar to accessing a `list` (a `data.frame` is internally a `list` as well).

```
> df.o[["ABC"]] # or equivalently as df$ABC
# [1] 2 3 3
```